# Can I assign some attributes to a TextView in the xml and then change the properties programmatically?

Tags: android, runtime, textview

Is this possible to change attributes of an object programmatically even though if it is defined in xml file. I am not really able to do this so suspecting if it allowed.

for example:

```
fillText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);    
fillText.setText("Hello World");   
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say **you first need to load the XML layout** :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

This will define the objects, and set them with default values, depending on what's in the XML file.

**Only then**, you can find the Views :

```
fillText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

And, then, change the values :

```
fillText.setText("Hello World");
```

I've done that a great number of times, and, yes, it is possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. All calls to `findViewById`  must be done after call to `setContentView`
2. After you init content view for your activity you can alter most of views attributes

Answer (score 0):

Ya, U can change values in the code. In your code keep ur

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

on top and then give:

```
fillText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);    
fillText.setText("Hello World");
```

Hope this may work perfectly..